# $\mathrm{i}\epsilon$ prescription makes a function analytical?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization, wick-rotation, analyticity

I've seen this everywhere where they say "Analytic continuation is obtained by the usual $\mathrm{i}\epsilon$ prescription..." but how is that?

How do you analytically continue (say) $\ln x$ with this prescription? What does it even mean in this context? I myself just let $x$ be complex and be done with it.

Comment: By the comment that "analytic continuation is gotten with the iepsilon prescription", they don't mean that the prescription is a universal tool to determine any continuation, and so on. They just mean that there could be an ambiguity which branches of various functions you pick, and the right answer is that you move the singularities on the proper side away from the real axis, as dictated by the iepsilon prescription... For ln(x) with a singularity near the pole where i.epsilon is, the prescription would mean that ln(negative) would have the imaginary part +pi (or -i.pi, I am not sure)

Comment: It's an analytic continuation for a specific function, namely the propagator, which looks like $f(z) = 1/(z^2 - \omega^2)$ (relabeling $k \rightarrow z$ etc.). That guy has poles at $z = \pm \omega$ so you cannot integrate over the real axis, which is what you need to do in practice. By adding $i\epsilon$ to the denominator, you do NOT make the function holomorphic: it still has two poles, but they shift by a tiny amount, so the function is defined on the real axis and you can integrate as you please.

Comment: Let me respond to your remark "let $x$ be complex and be done with it" with another question: what is the value of $\ln -1$?

Comment: @ Vibert ...
That depends on the branch we choose.

Comment: This prescription chooses the branch. First you say that $\ln( x+i\epsilon)$ for $x>0$ is defined so that the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ gives you the usual real logarithm. Then you note that for $\epsilon>0$ this $\ln(x+i\epsilon)$ does not run into singularities when you do the continuation along real $x$. In this specific case it is equivalent to picking a branch cut along the negative imaginary axis, $\ln(-1+i\epsilon)=i\pi$